# Get CognitoId from Authenticated User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify framework to bring my idea to life, so far so good except for one thing I'm stuck with.

I let the authenticated users to upload files to S3 and I'm using **Protected** access level, according to [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js), Protected is readable by all users, I already managed to upload the files and save some info in a Dynamo table.

The Storage documentation states the following:

> Protected: Readable by all users, but writable only by the creating
> user. Files are stored under protected/{user_identity_id}/ where the
> user_identity_id corresponds to the unique Amazon Cognito Identity ID
> for that user.

BUT I'm not being able to match the {user_identity_id} created in S3 under Protected with none of the info available in Cognito User Pool, so, I really can't find a way of knowing which files belong to a particular user, furthermore, I need a way to let my **Admin** users be able to see the files uploaded by all the users.

On the other hand, [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/list/q/platform/js#protected-level-list), the docs say one can retrieve a file by passing the **identityId** as a parameter, but:

- **How do I retrieve the IdentityId for a particular user?**
- **How can I find the CognitoUser based on the IdentityId saved in S3?**

I'll appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What you need is cognito federated identity. Set the cognito user pool as authenticated provider then.

Comment: Let me know whether you request the s3 through API or SDK?

Comment: @MahdiRidho Thanks, if by federated you mean Facebook or Google? then not, I'm using cognito identity pools. For S3 I'm using aws-amplify package, using the Storage class.

Comment: No, there are 2 cognitos. User pool and federated identity. User pool is to manage user authentication layer, it will generate an oauth2 based token (jwt). Federated identity is to manage the user identity role. Every users should be a role to work with AWS services. You should set the auth identity provider with user pool.

Comment: So once login succeed and got a token, you will be able to exchange the token to AWS temp credential as auth identity role. There you go to have access into AWS services based on defined policies

Comment: in other words, user pool will be a federated identity for authenticated role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think understand where did you go. I never used AWS Amplify, but the basic concept is like I mentioned above to generate identityId. On diagram block, it will be like so :

[image: User Authorization]

IdentityId is the unique ID for every federated identity role, can be authenticated either unauthenticated roles. We will call [CognitoIdentityCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html#constructor-property) to exchange the token with aws temp credentials as authenticated role. Once users have credentials, they will have AWS.config.credentials with identityId included.

Back to your question, I found "Auth.currentUserCredentials()" method to get user identityID with amplify lib. Example:

```
let creds = await Auth.currentUserCredentials()
console.log(creds.identityId)
```

Then, based on the amplify doc you can retrieve your pretected s3 by example :

```
Storage.list('photos/', { 
   level: 'protected', 
   identityId: creds.identityId
})
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thanks @MahdiRidho. Yes Auth.currentUserCredentials() serves my purpose. Tho with additional logic, I saved the IdentityId in my User table, because I needed a way to display the files not only for the authenticated user but for the Admins as well, this way I can display a list with the files every user have uploaded.

Comment: BTW, I can tell I'm missing too much AWS concepts knowledge because by using amplify every aspect becomes automagically configured by just running a few CLI commands.

Comment: @arosgab I started my AWS 4 yrs ago through this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/. It has updated to version 3 now, I was version 2